# change color icon when I add movie to favorite in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I have a problem with the Angular application

I want to change the color of the icon when I add the movie to favorites

I tried to use ngStyle but there is an error that I can't find

This is my code

movies.component.ts

```
addToFavorit(movies: Movies, user: User) {
    this.AuthService.postToFav(user.id, movies.id).subscribe((s) => {
      if (
        this.users.favouriteMovies.find(
          (s) => s.movieId == movies.id && s.userId == user.id
        )
      ) {
        this.users.favouriteMovies.splice(s.movieId, 1);
      } else {
        this.users.favouriteMovies.push(s);
      }
    });
  }

public colorIcon(movies: Movies, user: User) {
    if (
      this.users.favouriteMovies.find(
        (s) => s.movieId == movies.id && s.userId == user.id
      )
    ) {
      return { color: 'red' };
    } else {
      return { color: 'gray' };
    }
  }
```

movie.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-cols-3 g-3 m-2">
    <div class="col" *ngFor="let item of movies">
      <div class="card">
        <img
          class="card-img-top"
          [src]="createImgPath(item.image)"
          alt="Card image cap"
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">
            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
            bulk of the card's content.
          </p>
          <button routerLink="details/{{ item.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">
            Details
          </button>
          <span class="float-end align-middle" *ngIf="users"
            ><fa-icon
              (click)="addToFavorit(item, users)"
              [icon]="faHeart"
              [ngStyle]="colorIcon(item, users)"
              size="xl"
            ></fa-icon
          ></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is shown in the picture
A loop is performed on all films after the first change, and when the films are finished, they work well
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fx2bS.gif)

That the icon be changed only in the movie that I want to add to my favourites, knowing that the backend works well and the data is not changed there and when you refresh the page everything is fine

Comment: Thanks for the code, could you please also include an example of an array of movies, e.g. the `movies` in your `let item of movies`? Ideally this data structure should be capable of storing the favourited state, e.g. with a boolean property `isFavourited`. You should not need to implement something like `colorIcon` which has to do a lookup against all movies every time for all cards

Comment: My movies array contains only movie information, while the matrix for the user who is actually logged in contains the favoriteMovies array and contains movies that have already been added to favorites and retrieved from the database.
Object { id: 2, username: "ass", email: "asss", password: "asss", firstName: "NUasLL", lastName: null, address: null, role: "user", favouriteMovies: (3) […] }
​
address: null
​
email: "asss"
​
favouriteMovies: Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​
firstName: "NUasLL"
​
id: 2
​
lastName: null
​
password: "asss"
​
role: "user"
​
username: "ass"

Comment: and here is my movies array 
Object { id: 1, title: "as", description: "as", … }
​​
coverImage: null
​​
description: "as"
​​
gender: "as"
​​
id: 1
​​
image: null
​​
releaseDate: "2012-12-12T00:00:00"
​​
title: "as"